# shared preferences for storing a single score

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am developing this quiz game. at the end of the game I show the user a detailed total score. What I want to develop here is a using sharedpreferences to store the value, be able to retrieve it using other activity showing the user's total score. I am only interested in storing one score for the quiz (initially). The reason I want to implement this is that in the future I will apply this for other quiz modes and show the total score for all quizzes in one activity called highscores. below is my code, and the variable finalscore(int) is storing the score of the user. My code is a mess but I can't quite figure this out so if anyone can help me with the implementation of shared preferences using my code I would appreciate it a lot, in order to get a better understanding.

**Update 3.0**

```
public static final String PREFS_FILE = "prefsFile";
SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putInt(PREFS_FILE, finalScore);
        editor.commit();
```

TotalScore Activity

```
public class TotalScore extends Activity {
TextView easy, totalScoreHeading;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_total_score);

    totalScoreHeading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalScoreHeading);
    easy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewTotalScoresEasy);

    totalScoreHeading.setTextSize(28);

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(ScoreActivity.PREFS_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int defaultValue = 0;
    int highscore = sharedPref.getInt(ScoreActivity.PREFS_FILE, defaultValue);
    easy.setText("" + highscore);

}
```

}

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What doesn't work? What errors are you getting?

Comment: updated the question see last sentence. problem here is finalScoreString is not identified

Comment: editor.putInt("finalScoreString",finalScore);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using **finalScoreString's** value as key to store final score in shared preferences. This variable is not available in your other activity, hence your problem. It would be advisable to follow the good practice of defining a key as:

```
public static final String FINAL_SCORE = "finalScore";
```

Do this in your main activity, where you save score

```
editor.putInt(FINAL_SCORE, finalScore);
```

Then, in other activity, use it to retrieve score:

```
int highscore = sharedPref.getInt(MainActivity.FINAL_SCORE, defaultValue)
```

As a matter of fact, you should also use a static key for Shared Preferences file name, instead of hardcoded "LevelScores" string.

This will also mitigate another problem you might have, with the following lines:

```
finalScore = timeLeft * QuizActivity.correct;
finalScoreString = String.valueOf(finalScore);
```

With this, whatever the value of finalScore, is being used as key to store final score in preferences. But this value might (and probably will) be different each time, meaning that your key will also change. In the end, you would have lots of entries with different keys in preferences. How would you know which one you want to use to get the corresponding value? By using public static key (or keys for different game modes foe example), your final score(s) could be easily retrieved, because you know exactly which key to use.

Comment: perfectly understood what you are suggesting here. can you suggest me an implementation for static key in replacement to the "LevelScores" string?

Comment: it crushes as soon as the other activity is lunched to view the highscores. please see updated section on question to check the updated code and let me know if I did everything ok

Comment: Do you have txtViewTotalScoresEasy in layout of your TotalScore activity? Also, did you call setView() before calling findViewById()? For "LevelScores", just do exactly the same as with FINAL_SCORE key - declare it in one activity, and use instead of hardcoded string.

Comment: what value should i reference for the easy.setText(?) in order to see the score stored in sharedpreferences?please check updated version 2.0

Comment: int highscore = sharedPref.getInt(ScoreActivity.FINAL_SCORE, defaultValue); easy.setText(highscore); is correct. See my questions in previous comment though...

Comment: please check the update version... sorry I just dont know what to do here. the app crashes as soon as TotalScore activity is lunched. i did not call setView() method as I never used that before.

Comment: Do you have txtViewTotalScoresEasy component in activity_total_score layout xml file?

Comment: yes I do I am referencing it correctly using     easy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewTotalScoresEasy);
 Please see the logcat I hope it helps.....

Comment: I wasn't asking about totalScoreHeading. See my previous comment. Also, come to think of if, you're using setText() with an int, and one of the overloaded setText() methods takes an int as resource id, so because there is no resource with whatever you're passing to setText(), you have an exception. Instead, pass string, eg. easy.setText("" + highscore); ' ""+ ' will convert your highscore to string

Comment: Btw, use something else for file name key, eg. public static final String PREFS_FILE = "prefsFile"; then do not declare it in every activity, because you can use it as every static variable, by using class name and variable name, as you're already doing it, eg. ScoreActivity.PREFS_FILE.

Comment: no sure what the problem was but I have update the question into version 3.0 using you suggestions. thank you for your time it works. I have one more question tho, if i want to store other values for quiz mode 'medium' how should i do it?

Comment: PREFS_FILE - use only in getSharedPreferences(), FINAL_SCORE - use to save/retrieve your final score value. If you want to save final score in medium mode, just add another key, eg. FINAL_SCORE_MEDIUM. I suggest you read the answer and these comments again. In other words, for each unique value (such as shared prefs file name, final score in normal mode, final score in medium mode, define a unique key as static variable accessible from one class. You can also use string resources, see here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: sorry I didn't get the chance to thank you for all the support you gave me. I have one last question, if I want to store only the highest score what implementation are you suggeesting me?

Comment: The same implementation as above. It doesn't matter what you want to store, just choose a key and save in shared preferences, then use the same key to retrieve the value when needed.