# how save first three best scores

Tags: android-edittext, max, savechanges

How save best first three scores or only best score, I am new in  programming.
I have score, but how define new score and old score.

```
public class HighScores extends Activity {

    private TextView thighscore1;
    private TextView thighscore2;
    private TextView thighscore3;
    public TextView name;
    public   int highscore1 =0;
    public   int highscore2 =0;
    public   int highscore3 =0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_high);

        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Names);
        thighscore1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.highscore1);
        thighscore2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.highscore2);
        thighscore3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.highscore3);

        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        int score = prefs.getInt("key", 0); //0 is the default value
        thighscore1.setText("" + score);
        if(score > highscore2) {
            highscore1 = score;
            thighscore1.setText("" + highscore1);
        }else{
            highscore1=highscore1;
        }
        if(score > highscore3 && score < highscore1){
            highscore2 = score;
            thighscore2.setText("" + highscore2);
        }else{
            highscore2 = highscore2;
        }
        if (score > 0 && score < highscore2){
            highscore3 = score;
            thighscore3.setText("" + highscore3);
        }else{
            highscore3 = highscore3;
        }

        SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences("MyKey",0);
        String data = sp.getString("tag", "");
        name.setText(""+ data);
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For setting scores in Preference:**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PreferenceName",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putInt("Score1", highscore1);
editor.putInt("Score2", highscore2);
editor.putInt("Score3", highscore3);
editor.apply();
```

**For retrieving scores from Preference:**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("PreferenceName",MODE_PRIVATE);
if(prefs.getString("text", null) != null) {
     int score1 = prefs.getInt("Score1", 0); // 0 is the default value
     int score2 = prefs.getInt("Score2", 0);
     int score3 = prefs.getInt("Score3", 0);
}
```

More information on [**SharedPreferences**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

**To delete any value from Preference**

```
editor.remove("highscore1"); // will delete highscore1
```

Comment: thank you, but I cant  resolve my problem I saving only new score. How define higher score  private void HighScore() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("key", number);
        editor.commit();

Comment: I can't understand exactly what do you want but if you want to update the previous highscore then I just edited my answer.

Comment: I know only:  int score1 = prefs.getInt("Score1", 0); // 0 is the default value  how I get score2 and score3  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit(); editor.putInt("key", Score1); editor.commit();

Comment: you can get score2 and score3 in the similar way as score1 check the answer I have mentioned it under For retrieving scores from Preference

Comment: its similar problem like my, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28918571/shared-preferences-for-storing-a-single-score?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

> I resolved my problem with score also have a name:

```
 if (number > prefs.getInt("key", 0)) {
                        editor.putInt("key", number);
                        editor.putString("tag", value);

                    } else if (number < prefs.getInt("key", 0)) {
                        if (number > prefs.getInt("key1", 0)) {
                            editor.putInt("key1", number);
                            editor.putString("tag1", value1);
                        }
                    }
                    if (number < prefs.getInt("key1", 0)) {
                        editor.putInt("key2", number);
                        editor.putString("tag2", value2);
                    }
```